# JQuery UI Autocomplete searches the same respose

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm having a problem with Autocomplete. I can do an initial search fine but if I want to search in the same input again it only searches the previously returned results, if I try to check if any there were any results the response ui object at this point throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null.

I have to reload the page to be able to search again with the autocomplete, how can I fix this?

```
jQuery(this).autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    response: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
            console.log("No results found");
        } else {
            console.log(ui.content.length + " results were found");
        }
    },
    source: "index.php?option=com_casehandler&format=raw&task=autocomplete&table=" + table + "&column=" + column + "&term=" + jQuery(this).val(),
    minLength: 0,
    delay: 500,
    search: function () {
        console.log('searching...' + "index.php?option=com_casehandler&format=raw&task=autocomplete&table=" + table + "&column=" + column + "&term=" + jQuery(this).val());
        jQuery(this).data().term = null;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        jQuery(this).val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit j08691, I dont know why it got all jarbled up like that

Comment: could you throw it in a fiddle?  but just at a glance, 0 !== null

Comment: its running on a local server so I can't specify the source parameter correctly in a fiddle. But heres an example of JSON that gets sent to autocomplete when searching for "Rolf":
[{"namn":"Fredricsson Rolf","value":"Fredricsson Rolf"},
...
Rolf","value":"Andersson Rolf"},{"namn":"Fransson Rolf","value":"Fransson Rolf"}]

Now, if I search again, i can get results fine if I start with "Rol-" for example, but if i search For something else that I know that I have in the databse and that delivers results if I reload the page like "Nilsson" I get no results.

Comment: so why are you using `content` as a key for that json if it doesn't exist?  ui[0].name = Fredricsson Rolf

Comment: I'm using the response content to see if there were any search results, mainly there was an example showing that and I thought it would be a useful debugging feature. however the problem persists without the response function as well. It is the select function that I really need to work, there I use ui.item.value which should access for example value: fredricsson Rolf, if I've understood everything correctly.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, thank you all for taking your valuable time to try to help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with my SQL, I was selecting from two different databases and using union to merge the results, however for the first selection I had forgotten to include a where statement so all results were taken from there. As I had put a limit of 10 items no other results could be displayed.